How to change the Order of Tabs without rebuilding the TabBar from scratch?
In a Shell scenario of hard coded XAML, I keep track of the usage of each Tab or category. I would like to be able to dynamically change the positions of Tabs based on the ranking of each one. I thought this might be as easy as changing the index of each Tab or changing the order of TabBar items TabBarName.Items.OrderBy( i => i.Ranking). But it appears this is more complicated than I originally thought since I can GetIndex of a Tab but not set the Index. Plus, the Items property of the TabBar is Read only.
What's the most efficient way to accomplish this task without having to Clear TabBar Items and rebuilding the TabBar and Items again from scratch as discussed in this thread?
To clarify a little bit more, I would like to be able to change the order of bottom Tabs in the following classic example; for example, Elephants comes first, Bears second, Monkeys third, and Domestic last:


I don't think it's possible to dynamically change the order of bottom Tabs without clearing the TabBar Items. Also, you can use  Shell.CurrentItem property to set to the first Tab object, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-8.0#tab-selection.

Look into binding your animals to the itemsproperty in the shell section instead of hardcoding those animals into the XAML. That way, in the backend you can modify the item list's to any order you like and it will reflect it in the UI.

Can you please elaborate on how to bind to ItemsProperty field when it's backed by a getter only Items property?

It appears that changing the indexes of Tabs without having to destroy the TabBar Tabs or items is not possible. With that said, the easiest way I have tested so far is:

Save the current items/tabs after reordering them as you wish
var TabBarItems = TabBarName.Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Title).ToList();


Clear your TabBar of the current items
TabBarName.Items.Clear();


Loop through each item you saved earlier and add to the TabBar
foreach (var i in TabBarItems) {
    TabBarName.Items.Add(i);
}



